# Optimization problem using MIP

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to solve the following mixed integer programming problem. However, I have any problems with the approach of the model.

> **Problem:** A company that sells athletic shoes aims to make the following sales: 
> February: $31$ || March:    $46$ || April:    $21$ || May:      $51$. Also it is known that in the month of January $20$ sports shoes remained unsold.
> *Formulate a mixed integer programming problem (**MIP**) that minimize total cost. Subject to the following constraints:* $(1)$ At the end of all sales, nothing should be left in inventory, $(2)$ the quantity sold in each month must be the one that was ordered to be sold, $(3)$ for each unit of shoe that is not sold in a month, $\$5.00$ must be subtracted from the profit and doubled if it is two months and $(4)$ each shoe has a purchase cost of $\$ 70$, but if you buy more than $34$ shoes, you receive a $19\%$ discount for the other shoes purchased i.e., if you buy $39$ shoes, you will receive a $19\%$ discount for all $5$ shoes of the $39$ shoes purchased.

**My approach:**

**Data:**

$\mathbf{i}:$ the set $S_{i}=\{{\rm February}, {\rm March}, {\rm April}, {\rm May}\},$
$\mathbf{n}$: cardinal of $S_{i}$.
$\mathbf{m}$: cardinal of shoes purchased in month $\mathbf{i}$.
$\mathbf{u}_{i}$: quantity to sell for each $\mathbf{i}$.

**Variables:**

$\mathbf{x_i}$: quantity of shoes purchased in $\mathbf{i}$ without discount.
$\mathbf{y_i}$: quantity of shoes purchased in $\mathbf{i}$ with discount.
$\mathbf{z_{i,i+1}}$: shoes that are left over in month $\mathbf{i}$ and will be sold in month $\mathbf{i + 1}$.
$\displaystyle \mathbf{w_i}=\begin{cases}1, \quad m>34\\ 0, \quad m\leqslant 34 \end{cases}$ binary variable.

**Constraints:**

- At the end of all sales, nothing should be left in inventory:

$$z_{{\rm may},{\rm june}}=0$$

- the quantity sold in each month must be the one that was ordered to be sold: $$\sum_{i}^{n}x_{i}+y_{i}\leqslant u_{i}$$

But I don't know how to formulate the constraints $(3)$ and $(4)$.

**Objective function:**

The objective function is the cost, but how can I write it using the information above?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you sure you want to *maximize* cost?

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you for your observation. I will correct the problem. I want to minimize the total cost.

Comment: Can we categorize this problem in a known  MIP problem?

Comment: It is *production planning* with *volume discounts*.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like reasonable variables, but your inventory balance constraints should instead be
$$z_{i-1,i} + x_i + y_i = u_i + z_{i,i+1} \quad \text{for all $i$}.$$

You can enforce $y_i>0 \implies w_i =1$ with linear big-M constraint $y_i \le M_i w_i$.

You can enforce $w_i=1 \implies x_i \ge 34$ with linear constraint $x_i \ge 34 w_i$.

The objective function is
$$\sum_i \left(70x_i + 70(1-0.19)y_i + 5z_{i,i+1}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand that constraint. Is there another constraint? How can I write the objetive function? I couldn't see that.

Comment: I guess I need other restrictions for the conditional purchase there I could use w_i and for the objective function I could also use it I think. But I don't know how yet.